# Vb6 find replace code

Tags: vba, vb6

i want to replace only 1 string but what happens is it replaces all matching strings.

i selected Ball from list1(listbox ) and find and replace that on text1 , it finders the value in text1 but other strings similar to the name ball gets changed also.

i have a list1
i have text1.text  multiline

**list1 keywords**
ground
swimming
snooker
Ball
james

**text1.text**
hiker
Ball
Balla
jeans

am using

```
If Text1.Text = list1.Text Then
Text1 = Replace(Text1.Text, list1.Text, Text9.Text)
end if
```

am trying to do exact keyword replace here but am failing to do so.

am trying to **replace Ball** only but it replaces all matching keywords all together

Ball should be replaced only but Balla also geting replaced

Comment: I'm forced to make some assumptions here: Is 'List1' a listbox and you select ONE of the values in the list (i.e. 'Ball')? And is your ONLY issue that the strings 'Ball' and 'Balla' in 'Text1'  are being replaced, or is there some other issue in addition to that? For 'Ball/Balla' you will need to delimit the search string. You say 'multilinje' so does that mean either a Line Feed or CRLF is at the end of each word? Will you want to replace a partial word (i.e. change nighttime to daytime)?

Comment: i have list1 which is listbox with the string Ball selected now i do simple replace method on text1,  it replaces the string in text1 but other similar string Ball Balla also gets replaced, i strictly want to replace selected value only

Comment: As I stated earlier, you need to delimit the search. You did not answer my question re CRLF or how your multiline is delimited.

Comment: You *may* be able to use REPLACE, but depending on how your delimiters work, you may need to write your own routine. For example, if 'Text1' only has one word per line, AND there is a CRLF (or similar) to delimit, you can change the REPLACE to look like: Text1 = Replace(Text1.Text, list1.Text & vbcrlf, Text9.Text & vbcrlf)  However, if the last line has no CRLF, that will not work.

Comment: i am loading the text1 from a .htm file , the text1 gets populated with html code so thier is alot of space and vbcrlf in it

Answer (score 0):

`RegExp` is excellent to catch *whole word*, without the need to specify any specific boundaries. If you want to use this feature, try this:

```
Function ReplaceWholeWord(sText As String, sFind As String, sReplace As String)
  With CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
     .MultiLine = True: .Global = True
     .Pattern = "\b" & sFind & "\b"
     ReplaceWholeWord = .Replace(s, sReplace)
  End With
End Function
```

---

```
Sub Test()
  Dim s As String
  s = "hiker " & vbCrLf & "Ball 123" & vbCrLf & "Balla" & vbCrLf & "Ball" & vbCrLf & "foobar"
  Debug.Print ReplaceWholeWord(s, "Ball", "Crystal")
End Sub
```

Comment: debug.print shows output as footbar now sure what this is doing , is it replacing Ball with footbar ?

Comment: @RobRob it replaces whole word "Ball" with "Crystal". "foobar" is just the last line and it stays the same. Only the two occurrences of the word `"Ball"` are replaced. It is tested :)

Comment: can i use this on text1 with lots of html code loaded onto it and then using this code to find and replace , will i se the changs.

Comment: i think this is not what i want, i want find and replace , i have string Ball Balling , i want to replace Ball Only , but it replaces all Ball strings instead

Comment: @RobRob Try `text1 = ReplaceWholeWord(text1, text2, text3)`.

Comment: i think this is not what i want, i want find and replace , i have string Ball Balling , i want to replace Ball Only , but it replaces all Ball strings instead   text1.text is loaded from file its html code so i have to find and replace

Comment: @RobRob it does **not** replace Balling. Idk what is actually in your html text but the pattern replace only *whole words*. If that's not what you want then I misunderstood the question.